# Flutter - Read Nested Maps from Cloud Firestore

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble trying to read a map inside of another map from Cloud Firestore. I've found several posts on the internet regarding the subject, but as a beginner in both flutter and firebase I wasn't capable of adapting those cases to mine.

In Firebase Firestore I have the following data example, which belong to a 'media' collection:

[image: Firebase Firestore Example]

I was capable to read almost all the data, including an array (using a cast), but the 'ingredients' is really giving me a lot of pain. It is a `Map<String, Quantity>` and quantity is a class of mine:

```
class Quantity {
  final double amount;
  final String unit;

  const Quantity({
    required this.amount,
    required this.unit,
  });
  String toString() => '$amount $unit';
}
```

It is quite simple for now, but will grow with more methods that will use the double value. That's the reason I don't want to get rid of it and simplify the database entry.

I need to read all the data using a Stream Builder and pass it to a ListView.buider, like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('media')
          .orderBy('initials')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext ctx,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> media) {
        if (media.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        var docs = media.data!.docs;
        var box = Hive.box<Favorite>('favorites');

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: media.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
            Medium md = Medium(
              initials: docs[i].get('initials'),
              longName: docs[i].get('longName'),
              ingredients: <String, Quantity>{}, // docs[i].get('ingredients'),
              steps: docs[i].get('steps').cast<String>(),
              mediumState: PhysicalState.values.elementAt(
                docs[i].get('mediumState'),
              ),
              reference: docs[i].data().containsKey('reference')
                  ? docs[i].get('reference')
                  : '',
              isComplement: docs[i].data().containsKey('isComplement')
                  ? docs[i].get('isComplement')
                  : false,
              ps: docs[i].data().containsKey('ps') ? docs[i].get('ps') : '',
            );

            if (box.get(docs[i].get('initials')) == null) {
              box.put(
                docs[i].get('initials'),
                Favorite(
                  initials: docs[i].get('initials'),
                  isFavorite: false,
                ),
              );
            }

            return MediumCard(
              medium: md,
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The Medium constructor being called is this one:

```
class Medium {
  final String initials;
  final String longName;
  final Map<String, Quantity> ingredients;
  final List<String> steps;
  final PhysicalState mediumState;
  String reference;
  bool isComplement;
  String ps;

  Medium({
    required this.initials,
    required this.longName,
    required this.ingredients,
    required this.steps,
    required this.mediumState,
    this.reference = '',
    this.isComplement = false,
    this.ps = '',
  });
}
```

I could post a lot attempts and error messages but the post would be unnecessarily long, so only one attempt, trying to use the same logic of the other entries `docs[i].get('ingredients')`, which gives me this:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Quantity>'
```

It's important to note that the number os Quantity(s) inside the 'ingredients' may vary and will not always be the same two of the example above (Water and Agar).

So finally, the question. How do I adapt the import of 'ingredients' in my `ListView.builder` code to correctly read that part of the data from Firebase?

I'm on `Flutter 2.2.3`, `cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0` and `firebase_core: ^1.4.0`

Ps.: Sorry for any English errors. I'm not a native speaker ("writer").

Comment: Hi @Rodrigo, can I check if your 'steps' map is dynamic(meaning the number of steps can change)? If so, how do you map it in flutter? I'm facing a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052105/how-to-map-dynamic-map-object-from-firestore-into-flutter-and-from-flutter-to-fi . Would love to hear your thoughts on it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @scottlee. My steps is indeed of dynamic size. The piece of code I use to parse this information from firestore is this:

`steps: doc.data().containsKey('steps') ? doc.get('steps').cast<String>() : <String>[],`.

It is important to notice that my 'steps' data is actually an array in firestore wich corresponds to a List in Dart/Flutter not a map.

I will take a look at the issue you linked. If a have any ideas on how to help I will post there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more attemps and failures, I was capable of solving my issue with this addition to the `ListView.builder` code:

```
    var docs = media.data!.docs;
    var box = Hive.box<Favorite>('favorites');

    Map<String, Quantity> myIngredients = {};

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: media.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
        // Convert data from firebase into <String, Quantity>
        Map.from(docs[i].get('ingredients')).entries.forEach((e) {
          myIngredients[e.key] = Quantity(
            amount: e.value['amount'].toDouble(),
            unit: e.value['unit'],
          );
        });

        Medium md = Medium(
          initials: docs[i].get('initials'),
          longName: docs[i].get('longName'),
          ingredients: myIngredients,
          steps: docs[i].get('steps').cast<String>(),
          mediumState: PhysicalState.values.elementAt(
            docs[i].get('mediumState'),
          ),
          reference: docs[i].data().containsKey('reference')
              ? docs[i].get('reference')
              : '',
          isComplement: docs[i].data().containsKey('isComplement')
              ? docs[i].get('isComplement')
              : false,
          ps: docs[i].data().containsKey('ps') ? docs[i].get('ps') : '',
        );
```

So using `Map.from` approach I was capable of setting up a `Map<String, Quantity>` instance and use it.

If anyone finds a better, cleaner solution, I would like to see it.
Thank you very much.