# How to Map Dynamic Map Object from Firestore into Flutter and from Flutter to Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to convert a dynamic map object on Firestore into Flutter. Below is an example:

The map for blocked users can change. Sometimes, it may contain 3 blocked users
[image]
Other times, it may contain 2.
[image]

Below is my current code:

```
    class UserModel {
      String userId;
      String bio;
    ///add in dynamic blockedusers mapping
    }
    
    UserModel(
          {
          this.userId,
          this.bio,
    ///add in dynamic blockedusers mapping
    }
    
    UserModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
        userId = map['userId'];
        bio = map['bio'];
    ///add in dynamic blockedusers mapping
    }
    
     toJson() {
        return {
          "userId": userId,
          'bio': bio,
    ///add in dynamic blockedusers mapping
    };
    }
```

Given that the map object changes, is there a way to dynamically map it from Firestore into Flutter or map it from Flutter into Firestore?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Scott. You probable are using it, but to be sure I will ask. Are you using cloud_firestore and firebase_core libraries as dependencies to import and export from/to flutter?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, the easiest is just storing it as a Map on the `UserModel`.

Or in dart you can map through them the create a list of strings: `List blockedUsers = blockedUsersFromDB.keys.toList()`.

Or if there is more information create a sub model with a static listfromjson:

```
class BlockedUser{
  final String id;
  BlockedUser({this.id});

  factory BlockedUser.fromMap(Map map){
    return BlockedUser(id: map['userId']);
  }

  static List<BlockedUser> listFromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json){
    // adjust to your data set or to use the from map function above
    return json.keys.map((user) => BlockedUser(id: user));
  }

}
```